# Power query problem with connection to files in iCloud Drive

Tags: excel, powerquery, icloud

So, we have a shared folder on iCloud and I need to make a connection with one of the tables on the cloud. Also, we have to work with both Windows and macOS versions of Excel.

Connection from Windows (Parallels Desktop) look like this and works fine:
\\Mac\iCloud\pathToFile

From macOS:
/Users/kirillkazakov/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/pathToFile

For different OS versions I need one of these path, I can't just choose the first one. (and, obviously it's better, since I don't need to specify username, therefore it can be a general path for each user)

When I just use first path I'm getting this error:

```
[DataSource.Error] Could not find file '/Users/kirillkazakov/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Microsoft-Mashup-Container/Data/\\mac\iCloud\pathToFile
```

So, could you help, how to get the data by the same way for each OS?

Comment: If you view the file online and then open it in the desktop app, what file path does it give under "info | copy path"? On either OS?

Comment: @Dolunaykiz 

MacOS - /Volumes/[OneDrive] Windows 10/pathToFile
Windows - C:\Users\kirillkazakov\OneDrive\pathToFile